# Populate not working, without populate the code is working

Tags: mongoose, populate

I am having problem populating the fields of a schema, I tried numerous time but I couldn't figure out the problem: 
FUNCTION:

```
 function xyz (req, res) {
    User.findOne({_id: req.payload._id })
        .populate("ABC.xyzID")
        .exec((err, user) => {
        if (err) {
            return res.json ({'success': false, 'message': 'Could not retrieve ABC.'});
        }
        console.log(user);
        return res.json ({'success': true, 'message': 'ABC fetched successfully', user });
    });

}
```

SCHEMA:

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name:{
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true
    },
ABC:{
        xyzID:{
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'xyz'
        },
},
LMN:{
          yyyID:[{
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'yyy'      
        }], 
         EmployeeID:[{
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'User'            
        }]
    }

});
```

here I can access: LMN.yyyID by populating it but it is not working for ABC.xyzID, without populate I can see the xyzID but in its _id format. So basically it'ss just populate which is not working

Comment: Do you get any error? As the query you are using is right.

Comment: man you try populate with single quote i.e .populate('ABC.xyzID') . That worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Please look at this Schema design. This is User.

```
// user.js

const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// Create schema
const UserSchema = new Schema({
    username: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
});

module.exports = User = mongoose.model('user', UserSchema);
```

Now Here is Activity Schema. Now as you can see I'm referencing userId from 'user' Schema. So you need to make sure your collection name and ref name are same. After this, it should work.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// Create schema
const ActivitySchema = new Schema({

    userId: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'user'
    },
    text: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
});

module.exports = Activity = mongoose.model('activity', ActivitySchema);
```

Then try Query

```
Activity.findOne({_id: req.payload._id })
     .populate('userId')
     .then(result => { console.log(result); })
     .catch(err => { console.log(err); });
```

You will see user information inside userId object.

Comment: Your answer doesn't help. You are just giving an example with a schema structure different from the OP one.